# Regexp for replacing reoccurring value in a string with random values

Tags: regex

Is it possible to create a regular expression that finds reoccurring value and replaces each instance with one randomly chosen predefined value?

Here is text to search in:

```
a f a f a f a ....
```

Letter `a` should be replaced, let's say with word '**apple**' OR '**table**'.

Comment: Please post your attempt.

Comment: Simply [`/a/g`](https://regex101.com/r/uJ8eO1/1)

Comment: All 'a' was replaced with 'apple', i need it to be randomly replaced with 'apple' or 'table'

Comment: Why is this tagged javascript and python? Which one are you using?

Comment: Thx to everybody but i need to know how to do this with only REGEXP without code on Python or JS or whatever language it will be.

Comment: @alex.rudoi You cannot do that by pure-regexp. Replacement should be unique.

Comment: ok so why using python or javascript tags ?

Comment: Really a great question ^

Comment: Sorry i am rookie here, system asked for some tags, added them without notice that they may confuse too :(

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript solution:**

Randomly replaces all occurrences of `a` with `apple` or `table`:

```js
var str = 'a f a f a f a ';

var re = /a/g;

var replacements = ['apple', 'table'];

var newStr = str.replace(re, function() {
  var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  return replacements[roll];
});

document.body.textContent = newStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern simply:

```
/a/g
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uJ8eO1/1)

- `/` delimiter
- `a` matches the character a literally *(case sensitive)*
- `g` global. All matches *(don't return on first match)*

---

```js
var string = 'a f a f a f a  ...';
var pattern = /a/g;
var replacements =['apple', 'table'];

var result = string.replace(pattern, function(re) {
  return replacements[Math.floor(Math.random() * replacements.length)];
});

document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like

```
yourString.replace(/a/g, "random");
```

Answer (score 0):

In **python**, you should use `replace()` string method:

```
c_str = 'a f a f a f a'
print c_str.replace('a', 'apple')
```

To randomly replace by 'apple' or 'table', you could use `random` module and `list comprehension`:

```
import random

words = ['apple', 'table']

c_str_new = ''.join([c.replace('a', words[random.randint(0, 1)]) for c in c_str])
```